# How is the width effected when using zoom?

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries, zooming

Code for reference: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvdyQb?editors=010

I'm having a hard time understanding how the width of the viewport changes when i zoom in/out. I have these media queries that are triggered when the width in em changes.

My question:
Why exactly does the viewport change when i zoom? Does it have to do with the font-size increasing/decreasing? em is used for the font-size of the parent container. If the body element defaults to 16px for font size, then 1em=16 pixels. How does this change when i zoom? Does 1em suddenly not equal 16px anymore but something bigger/smaller depending on how much i zoom? I am assuming the text size effects the size of the parent container as well but i am having trouble understanding how this effects the overall width of the page. How is width related to zooming and em? It looks like the width of the page gets smaller when i zoom in and bigger when i zoom out?

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
div#nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #888888;
}
div#logo {
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #1E3264;
  font-size: 2em;
}
@media (min-width: 50em) and (max-width: 99em) {
  #logo {
    background: orange;
    font-size: 0px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 100em) and (max-width: 149em) {
  #logo {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 150em) {
  #logo {
    display: initial;
  }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="logo">TEST</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are serious drawbacks of the styles or media queries you've used. 
First of all you must have a quite clear concept about media queries.

```
min-width
```

min-width means if your container width is at least equal to this width or more than that.
in responsive design, you design according to the maximum range, within which you want to run your query. So `max-width` is the correct choice for this situation. `min-width` is basically used for intervals. Like if you want to run a query specifically between `20em` and `30em`, then you will use `max-width:30em and min-width:20em` 
But if you want to run the query for maximum `20em` range, then you must use `max-width:20em` in your query. 
And in the case of responsive design, better use px. Because em is related with proportional sizes. But you have to give absolute ranges for media queries.
I hope this will help you a lot.

Comment: i was really curious to the zooming aspect in desktop based browsers. What happens to the web layout's width when we zoom in and out and how does it relate to the em for media queries? em is a sizing for font size and we know texts get bigger and smaller when we zoom in and out. the base font is 1em = 16pixels. does zooming in and out change what 1 em equals?

Answer (score 0):

Bro, em is the relative length parameter, that uses the already declared absolute font-sizes. Also it is important for you to know that `em` is not an absolute length parameter equals to `16px`.  `16px` is the default absolute font-size for chrome or whatever browser you are using. and when you use `1em`, it seems that `1em = 16px`. But it's not the case.   
If you set your defaults before styling contents, like if you set `html{ font-size:20px; }` then where ever you will use `1 em` within your container, it equals to `20px`.
So em is proportionally dependant on the default absolute font-sizes. It is not the exact value.

Comment: yes i understand this but how does it all relate when we zoom in and out? because when we zoom in the font is not the same as it was originally set. How does this effect the container of the texts getting bigger and how does that effect the overall width of a page and the media query with a certain width?

Answer (score 0):

Zooming will not affect em-based media queries. Neither will altering the `font-size` on the root `HTML` element (this will, however, affect the size of an em elsewhere in your css, such as font-size on child elements).

1em will generally be equivalent to 16px in media queries, unless the user has overridden their browser's default font sizing in their browser preferences. Typically, the default font sizing for browsers is 16px, however if they have set it to, say, 24px, then 1em will equal 24px; your 50em breakpoint would be equivalent to 1200px (50 x 24px) instead of 800px (50 x 16px).